# A continuous map $\Bbb{S}^n \hookrightarrow \Bbb{S}^1$ is null-homotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

> If $n\in \Bbb{N}, n\geq 2$ and $f : \Bbb{S}^n \hookrightarrow \Bbb{S}^1$ is continuous, then $f$ is null-homotopic.

This is a fact that appears as trivial on my class-notes, but I don't see why it is. I guess that it is related to the fact that $\Bbb{S}^n$ is simply connected and so $f_* : \pi_1 (\Bbb{S}^n) \hookrightarrow \pi_1 (\Bbb{S}^1)$ is the trivial homomorphism, which implies that for every path $\alpha : [0,1] \hookrightarrow \Bbb{S}^n$ we have that $f \circ \alpha$ is homotopic to a constant path on $\Bbb{S}^1$

I have tried using this to find a homotopy between $f$ and a constant map, but I am not reaching any point, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Standard proof would utilize fact that $S^1$ has contractible universal covering, i.e. $\mathbb{R}$. Looking at paths only is not good. I don't see how $f_*$ being trivial is relevant.

Comment: $f:S^n\to S^1$ is continuous so $[f]\in \pi_n(S^1)$, the $n-$th fundamental group of $S^1$. Since $n\ge 2$, $\pi_nS^1=0$. $[f]=0\implies f $ is homotopic to a constant map.

Comment: @Koro that's not a proof at all. You just used different symbols to say the same thing.

Comment: Note that the involved maps need not be injective (which you suggest by writing $\hookrightarrow$). With more technology, this is an immediate consequence from the Cellular Approximation Theorem by taking the standard CW structures on the spheres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{S}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^1$ be the induced map. It is clear that $\tilde{f}$ is null-homotopic. So $f$ is null homotopic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!